# How can i get all post of taxonomy category post by taxonomy category id or taxonomy category name in wordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created post type of products & also created taxonomy called productcategory.
Now i need to get particular category in related products.
Somehow i managed to find the taxonomy category id & name by using

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'productcategory', array("fields" => "ids"));
```

Now how can i get all post of this taxonomy category ?

Comment: Use `WP_Query` and specifically look at the [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameters

Answer (score 2):

Show posts associated with certain taxonomy. If specifying a taxonomy registered to a custom post type then instead of using 'category' you would use '{custom_taxonomy_name}'. For instance, if you had a custom taxonomy called "genre" and wanted to only show posts from the "jazz" genre you would use the below code.

```
 <?php
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 8,
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'post_type' => 'products',
     'productcategory' => 'your_cat_name',
     'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$show_albums = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'productcategory' );    

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'products',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'productcategory',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms' => explode(',',$terms),
    ),
),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then just run a loop using the results of this query and you should be good to go!